# Can tilemill display line as arrow

Tags: css, gis, tilemill, manifold

I am making a map in Tilemill map using OSM Bright as base map. I have added two shp files. One has markers on it and other lines. Shape file with lines represents rivers and I would like to display them as arrows (lines are divided into several sections). Can this be done in TileMill like it can be done in Manifold? (and how?)

Thanks for the info.

Comment: i figured it out... I used an url (image.svg) and did the trick just fine :)

Comment: Please mark this issue as resolved.